# How to calculate rotation in 2D in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rotation, trigonometry

I am not so familiar trigonometry, but I have only two points to rotate in 2D:

```
                    *nx, ny
               .     -
          .           -
     .  angle          -
*cx,cy.................*x,y
```

cx, cy = rotation center
x,y = current x,y
nx, ny = new coordinates

How to calculate new points in a certain angle?

Comment: So you have a triangle, and you're trying to calculate the the position of nx,ny when given a new angle?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
function rotate(cx, cy, x, y, angle) {
    var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle,
        cos = Math.cos(radians),
        sin = Math.sin(radians),
        nx = (cos * (x - cx)) + (sin * (y - cy)) + cx,
        ny = (cos * (y - cy)) - (sin * (x - cx)) + cy;
    return [nx, ny];
}
```

The first two parameters are the X and Y coordinates of the central point (the origin around which the second point will be rotated). The next two parameters are the coordinates of the point that we'll be rotating. The last parameter is the angle, in degrees.

As an example, we'll take the point (2, 1) and rotate it around the point (1, 1) by 90 degrees clockwise.

```
rotate(1, 1, 2, 1, 90);
// > [1, 0]
```

Three notes about this function:

1. For clockwise rotation, the last parameter `angle` should be positive. For counterclockwise rotation (like in the diagram you provided), it should be negative.
2. Note that even if you provide arguments that should yield a point whose coordinates are whole numbers -- i.e. rotating the point (5, 0) by 90 degrees about the origin (0, 0), which should yield (0, -5) -- JavaScript's rounding behavior means that either coordinate could still be a value that's frustratingly close to the expected whole number, but is still a float. For example:

   ```
   rotate(0, 0, 5, 0, 90);
   // > [3.061616997868383e-16, -5]
   ```

   For this reason, both elements of the resulting array should be expected as a float. You can convert them to integers using `Math.round()`, `Math.ceil()`, or `Math.floor()` as needed.
3. Finally, note that this function assumes a [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), meaning that values on the Y axis become higher as you go "up" in the coordinate plane. In HTML / CSS, the Y axis is inverted -- values on the Y axis become higher as you move *down the page*.

Comment: That was supposed to be "+". Thank you!

Comment: It seems about 50% of answers across SO have a "-" in the x formula, and the other half have it in the y formula.  In my case, it only seems to work in the y formula.  What's going on here?

Comment: @Michael I don't know if you're still looking for clarity on this 5 months later, but I've made some edits to the function so it's more generalized now.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to go revisit my work: I solved the problem somehow, and it seemed to work ok, but I don't recall what I did now...

Comment: This function works with Screen Coordinate Systems, only the direction of rotation reverses.

Comment: when i rotate with angle 0. It generates a new coordinate. I was assuming it would generate the same point when rotating 0 degree. Why is that so?

Comment: @JunaidShirwani, I can't replicate the behavior you described. Whenever I set the 5th argument (`angle`) to `0`, I always get an array containing the 3rd and 4th arguments (`[x, y]`) unmodified. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: With regards to the 3rd point made in the answer, if someone wants to use this function to get the coordinates with respect to how coordinate system works in DOM, a minor change will give the right output - just reverse the arithmetic sign in _nx_ and _ny_ formulas as follows:
`nx = (cos * (x - cx)) - (sin * (y - cy)) + cx,
ny = (cos * (y - cy)) + (sin * (x - cx)) + cy;`

Comment: Basic JavaScript visualisation here: https://codepen.io/spg-iwilson/pen/OJGmqQo

Answer (score 7):

1. First, translate the rotation center to the origin
2. Calculate the new coordinates (nx, ny)
3. Translate back to the original rotation center

**Step 1**

Your new points are

1. center: (0,0)
2. point: (x-cx, y-cy)

**Step 2**

1. nx = (x-cx)*cos(theta) - (y-cy)*sin(theta)
2. ny = (y-cy)*cos(theta) + (x-cx)*sin(theta)

**Step 3**

Translate back to original rotation center:

1. nx = (x-cx)*cos(theta) - (y-cy)*sin(theta) + cx
2. ny = (y-cy)*cos(theta) + (x-cx)*sin(theta) + cy

For deeper explanation, with some fancy diagrams, I recommend looking at [this](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/2drota.htm).

Answer (score 6):

above accepted answer not work for me correctly, rotation are reversed , here is working function

```
/*
 CX @ Origin X  
 CY @ Origin Y
 X  @ Point X to be rotated
 Y  @ Point Y to be rotated  
 anticlock_wise @ to rotate point in clockwise direction or anticlockwise , default clockwise 
 return @ {x,y}  
*/
function rotate(cx, cy, x, y, angle,anticlock_wise = false) {
    if(angle == 0){
        return {x:parseFloat(x), y:parseFloat(y)};
    }if(anticlock_wise){
        var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
    }else{
        var radians = (Math.PI / -180) * angle;
    }
    var cos = Math.cos(radians);
    var sin = Math.sin(radians);
    var nx = (cos * (x - cx)) + (sin * (y - cy)) + cx;
    var ny = (cos * (y - cy)) - (sin * (x - cx)) + cy;
    return {x:nx, y:ny};
 }
```

Comment: casting the coords to integer if the angle is zero will cut off decimals. you should at the very least cast to a float instead. also your parameters are upper case and your function uses them in lower case.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Polar coordinate system artycle on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates):

```
x = r * cos(deg)
y = r * sin(deg)
```

- `r` (*radius*) is equal to distance between `Rotation Centre` and `Rotated Point`
- `deg` (*degrees*) is angle measured in degrees

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use matrices for such operations.

Here is the example with gl-matrix (but you can use something like THREEJS as well).

```
import * as glm from 'gl-matrix';
const rotateVector = (() => {
  
  const q = glm.quat.create();  
  // const m = glm.mat4.create(); // 2nd way

  return (v: glm.vec3, point: glm.vec3, axis: glm.vec3, angle: number) => {

      glm.quat.setAxisAngle(q, axis, angle);
      // glm.mat4.fromRotation(m, angle, axis); // 2nd way
      glm.vec3.sub(v, v, point);
      glm.vec3.transformQuat(v, v, q);
      // glm.vec3.transformMat4(v, v, m); // 2nd way
      glm.vec3.add(v, v, point);
      return v;
  }
})();
```

In 2D case you need to rotate around z-axis:

```
rotateVector([x, y, 0], [cX, cY, 0], [0, 0, 1], angleInRadians);
```