# rotating svg polygon in 2D using javascript Math.sin, Math.cos

Tags: javascript, math, svg, rotation, polygon

I'm trying to rotate a svg polygon using javascript with `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`.  I have created a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Quick_Ric/pen/xxdYBZV) that illustrates what I am trying to do and the problem.  I am using `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` rather than `transform` because I need to access the coordinates of the rotated points.  Essentially my code:

```
var r = (Math.PI / 180.0) * a, 
    cos = Math.cos(r), 
    sin = Math.sin(r), 
    cx=350, cy=250;
for(var p of rectangle){
   p[0]=cos*(p[0]-cx)-sin*(p[1]-cy)+cx;
   p[1]=cos*(p[1]-cy)+sin*(p[0]-cx)+cy;
}
```

does not work correctly, with the rotated points not quite right.  They should be rotated anti-clockwise in 2D about `cx=350, cy=250`.  Instead the rectangle is distorted, seemingly doing a figure-8 in 3D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you're updating the x-coordinate of the rotated point (`p[0]`), and then using this updated value, rather than the original, in calculating the y-coordinate - been there, done that :)

```
p[0]=cos*(p[0]-cx)-sin*(p[1]-cy)+cx;
p[1]=cos*(p[1]-cy)+sin*(p[0]-cx)+cy;
```

Should be something like:

```
var rotX = cos*(p[0]-cx)-sin*(p[1]-cy)+cx;
var rotY = cos*(p[1]-cy)+sin*(p[0]-cx)+cy;
p[0] = rotX;
p[1] = rotY;
```

Or, better yet, define a function

```
const rotatePoint = (point, center, angle) => {
  const dx = point.x - center.x;
  const dy = point.y - center.y;
  const ca = Math.cos(angle);
  const sa = Math.sin(angle);
  const x = center.x + dx * ca - dy * sa;
  const y = center.y + dx * sa + dy * ca;
  return {x, y};
};
```

I don't see any need to be using `atan2` and `hypot` for this.

Comment: OMG! In the end it was all so simple!`p0=cos*(p[0]-cx)-sin*(p[1]-cy)+cx;
 p[1]=cos*(p[1]-cy)+sin*(p[0]-cx)+cy;
 p[0]=p0;`

Comment: I knew it would be something 'obvious' and 'simple' like that, but I just couldn't find it! Thanks so much @RaffleBuffle you have saved my sanity. Yes, `atan2` and `hypot` are only needed if you don't know the trig identities.

Answer (score 3):

`rotatePoint` function returns the `point` clockwise-rotated  around the `center`. The `angle` is given in radians:

```
const rotatePoint = (point, center, angle) => {
  const dx = point.x - center.x;
  const dy = point.y - center.y;
  const fromAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  const toAngle = fromAngle + angle;
  const radius = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  const x = center.x + radius * Math.cos(toAngle);
  const y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(toAngle);
  return {x, y};
};
```

```js
const rotatePoint = (point, center, angle) => {
  const dx = point.x - center.x;
  const dy = point.y - center.y;
  const fromAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  const toAngle = fromAngle + angle;
  const radius = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  const x = center.x + radius * Math.cos(toAngle);
  const y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(toAngle);
  return {x, y};
};

const svg = d3.select('svg');
const drawPath = points => points.forEach((p, i) => {
  const another = i === 0 ? points[points.length - 1] : points[i - 1];
  svg.append('line')
    .attr('x1', p.x)
    .attr('y1', p.y)
    .attr('x2', another.x)
    .attr('y2', another.y)
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke', 'black');
});

const centerP = {x: 100, y: 100};
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', centerP.x)
  .attr('cy', centerP.y)
  .attr('r', 5)
  .style('fill', 'red')

let rect = [
  {x: 110, y: 20}, 
  {x: 150, y: 20}, 
  {x: 150, y: 80}, 
  {x: 110, y: 80}
];
drawPath(rect);

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  rect = rect.map(p => rotatePoint(p, centerP, Math.PI / 3));
  drawPath(rect);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="250" height="200" />
```

Comment: Thanks for that Michael. I will see if I can get it working with your code. I'm curious to know what exactly is wrong with my code though. According to other stack answers it should work and be more efficient than what you have as it uses simplifying trig identities.

Comment: Great, @Michael with some minor tweaks to make it consistent with my code I got your function to work. I especially like the use of `Math.atan2` which calculates the angle in the correct quadrant, unlike `Math.atan` which doesn't work if, for example both `x` and `y` are negative.  I'd still like to know what is wrong with my code though.  As far as I can see it *should* work.  See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410809/how-to-calculate-rotation-in-2d-in-javascript) for example.

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011, the funtction in another answer works  as well, but it rotates the point counter-clockwise: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/17ybe0hg/

Answer (score 0):

Just to put this completely to bed, the answer, as posted by @RaffleBaffle, was to *not* use the updated `x` coordinate to update my `y` coordinate. Here is the working code after making the required change:

```
var r = (Math.PI / 180.0) * a, 
    cos = Math.cos(r), 
    sin = Math.sin(r), 
    cx=350, cy=250;
for(var p of rectangle){
   var p0=cos*(p[0]-cx)-sin*(p[1]-cy)+cx;
   p[1]=cos*(p[1]-cy)+sin*(p[0]-cx)+cy;
   p[0]=p0;
}
```

You see children, in the end it was *sooooo* simple and easy.  There was no need for those hours of fretting. And that is the story of computer programming. Goodnight now, pleasant dreams. xxx